# Redirect Request Rule with javascript

Tags: javascript, redirect

There is an extension for chrome called [Requestly](https://www.requestly.in/), and it allows you to redirect an address to one of your choosing. I tested out 'Redirect Request' rules, and it took a javascript url and redirected it to one on my public server. How can I immitate (or recreate) how 'Requestly' does this with javascript?

I've tried to redirect using `window.location.replace` and `window.location.href`, but that just redirects my entire page to the javascript source.

Comment: can u elaborate more on how this `javascript url` is redirected?

Comment: I cannot, since I do not know. I assume it is replacing the request headers with my website, which I put into the rule. You can check out the extension at https://www.requestly.in/ and try out 'Redirect Request'!

Comment: Assuming you are making a chrome extension, you could allow the user to give you a to/from mapping and then you could run your code on load. When you run it, you'd be checking if the url is 'rederictable' and if so, then you can use `window.location.href = <url>`

Comment: Sorry for not specifying- I am making a script for Tampermonkey. I could make an extension, and if that's the only way, then I will.

Comment: @Jacob BTW Requestly also has a Script Rule feature using which you can create Scripts for a domain (Quite similar to TamperMonkey)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is **YOU CANNOT INTERCEPT JS/CSS requests from JS CODE and do the Redirect**.

I think you want to achieve Redirection capability in your JS Code. In [Requestly](https://requestly.in), we are doing a bunch of things to provide the Redirect functionality.

In short, if you need the ability to redirect, **you need more power than just JS APIs, you need Chrome Extension APIs**

You can easily find a simple example to setup Redirect on Chrome WebRequest API docs.

**Disclaimer**: Sachin, Founder @ Requestly

Comment: I guess making an extension would be the better option.

Comment: @Jacob There are a few existing addons in the market which allows you to redirect. Do you have anything specific which is not covered by the existing products?

Comment: I really don't have anything specific, but I am exploring the Market as this conversation unfolds.

Comment: Sounds good @Jacob. Feel free to do so. I just wanted to save a few hours of your effort if there is anything specific you may not be able to find in the existing products.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a super basic example of how you could go about it. Essentially, allow some configurable list of redirects and then once the page loads, you can sniff our what the current location of what `window.location.href` is (in this case, the `iframe.src`) and if that url is in your redirect list, redirect the page.

I had to use an iFrame to demonstrate this, so there's obviously a layer of translation into what you're using/doing here.

Type in the address of `https://youtube.com/` into the address bar (the text box) and you can see how the basic approach can work.

```js
const redirectMaps = [
 {
   from: 'https://youtube.com/',
    to: 'https://youtube.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ'
  }
];

const address = document.getElementById('address');
const iframe = document.getElementById('myFrame');
address.addEventListener('change', () => {
 const url = address.value;
  iframe.setAttribute('src', url);
});

iframe.onload = (e) => {
 console.log('src', iframe.src);
 if (iframe.src) {
   const match = redirectMaps.find( src => src.from === iframe.src);
    if (match) {
     window.location.href = match.to;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
}

iframe {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <input id="address" />
  <iframe id="myFrame"></iframe>
</div>
```

Works better in JSFiddle.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/